# How to capture and extract this toast message using python's Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, toast

The toast pop out message just appears for two seconds. Its element is like

```
<div id class="layui-layer-content">abcde!</div>
```

How to capture the message and extract *abcde!*

Answer (score 2):

Use Explicit Wait `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `presence_of_element_located`() and following css selector.

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.layui-layer-content"))).text)
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: "wait...until.." is better than the loop method, but your code does not work.

Comment: @questionhang : It's working at my end. Strange!! what error are you getting?

Comment: it works today...but the toast messages are different and only appear for one or two seconds after clicking.Unless some particular message appears and is captured, i need to click again and check whether that particular message appears. There is a coding=utf-8 problem here. Can you capture the message and print it out like div.text below?

Comment: I mean how to capture that message usinig WebDriverWait and capture a particular message. If the message is different, run WebDriverWait again.

Comment: wait, capture a toast message, if the message is right, break; if wrong,  loop(wait and capture)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class = "layui-layer-content"]')
print(div.text)
```

**Edit:**

You can add this within a `while loop` to check whether the pop-up is present or not. If the pop-up is present you can display the text. Here is the code to do it:

```
while True:
    try:
        div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class = "layui-layer-content"]')
        print(div.text)
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        pass
```

Output:

```
卡号或密码错误！
```

Comment: It does not work. Empty. We need to wait and capture the message first, then extract it.

Comment: Could you provide the url of the website?

Comment: http://a.zwlp.com.cn/m.php/index/lkdh.html  Fill the two blanks with two numbers, then click the long horizontal button. A small window would pop out. Try to capture and extract its text.

Comment: @questionhang If my answer has helped u, pls accept it as the best answer. Thanks!

Comment: sometimes div.text is null or the message I do not want. I need to capture a particular message and avoid too many clicks.  WebDriverWait is better, but i can not extract the message it captures yet

Comment: This doesn't click on anything. Just run this while loop separately. Plus, it does not throw any error also, which is very good.

Comment: your loop method has too many clicks. wait, check a message, if the right one, good, if not , do it again. This is better

Comment: i need to capture a particular message

Comment: the toast message is irregular. sometimes it popups quickly after a click, sometimes not. Sometimes it appears long, sometimes not.

Comment: Oh...If it is so irregular, then I think tht this is the only way to do it